# Is it possible to host manifest.xml files for office-js via a webserver instead of a share drive?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

Is it possible to host manifest.xml files for office-js via a local webserver instead of a share drive?

Users are either using Word 2016 or Office 365 with an on-prem exchange.

Comment: The only ways to host the manifest are described in this article: [Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish)

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham - for Word 2016 or Office 365 with an on-prem exchange, Sideloading or Network Share are the only options for enterprises that do not have Sharepoing.      But they are both marked as "(Not for production add-ins.)" , which get IT departments concerned and sometimes refuse to use those methods.  What would you recommend them to do?

Comment: See if the technique in this blog post works for you: [Web Add-in Sideloader tool](https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/)

Comment: It would, but since sideloading is advertised as "(Not for production add-ins.)", IT is not comfortable doing it.

Comment: @RickKirkham - what is the the correct way we should explain the situation to IT departments, since they are not comfortable with the "(Not for production add-ins.)" notification?

Comment: I've consulted internally at Microsoft. I'm afraid your client will have to either switch to Exchange Online or SharePoint. Otherwise, they will have to live with a deployment method that is not recommended for production.

Comment: @emraldinho I'm starting w/ sideloading and collecting data stats to use to push for installation via Office 365 Admin Center further down the line. Good luck w/ your project, by far the hardest part of this is the deployment methods. They need to enable hosting in LAN without MS Software (Eg: A WebServer only). A webserver is already required to host JS files, so this makes sense too, but they continue to push their products on us not realizing the downsides (lack of adoption).

Comment: The worst part for me too is that Windows disabled Guest Access to SMB so I can't even setup a SMB Share on my Linux Box without passing a bogus Username and its just not as streamlined. I definitely worry it won't get the traction because of the bad deployment methods available.

Comment: @RickKirkham would it be possible to `(Not for production add-ins.)` from Side-loading section on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish then? It is scaring companies, and decreasing adoption

Comment: @emraldinho I'm having trouble understanding your question. Is there a word missing from your question? Should the word "remove" appear after the "to"?

Comment: @RickKirkham - apologies for the typo, I was meaning to ask if it is it possible to remove

Comment: @emraldinho I'm sorry, but no, we can't remove that statement.

Comment: @RickKirkham - thanks for the message, but that puts everyone in a tough situation. Basically, no production options for Word 2016 or Exchange on-premise?

Can we at least get an email or paper or something that proves that sideloading is the only way to go in those environments?